# User reference show user data-field

Tags: users

I have a view with user-reference. In the field 'data' in the table 'user' there's a serialized array with one element, named 'department'. I managed to show the department-value in the referencefield in the backend. I can't manage to show the department-value in the front-end. Which setting or code-changing do I have to change?

Comment: What version of Drupal are you using?